# Wp query posts between dates, but any year

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, acfpro

I'm using ACF pro and need to query posts that have some special ACF fields certain value.
But also I need to get posts that have ANY year, but the date should be between today and + 30 days from today. I cannot use static month number because then if post is made in day 1 it would not find it enough in advance.
Here is my initial query that is not working. It works if only get certain year and month, but that only gets posts from that date.

```
//$date_month_advance_month = ... month number of today + 30 days
//$date_month_advance_day= ... day number of today + 30 days
    // args
    $args = array(
        'post_type'     => 'my_post_type',
        'posts_per_page'=> -1,
        'meta_key'      => 'status',
        'meta_value'    => 'accepted',
        'date_query' => array(
         'compare'   => 'BETWEEN',
                 array(
                     'month' => $date_today_month,
                     'day'   => $date_today_day,
                 ),
                array(
                    'month' => $date_month_advance_month,
                    'day'   => $date_month_advance_day,
                ),
            ),
    );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a custom `query`. I made one quickly, tested for the date but not the custom field `status` as i don't have it. Replace `my_post_type` with your post type name.

```
global $wpdb;

$query = "
SELECT * FROM {$wpdb->posts} as p
LEFT JOIN {$wpdb->postmeta} as pm
ON pm.post_id = p.ID
WHERE p.post_type = 'my_post_type'
AND pm.meta_key = 'status'
AND pm.meta_value = 'accepted'
AND REPLACE(SUBSTRING(p.post_date, 6, 10), '-', '') BETWEEN %s AND %s
GROUP BY p.ID
";

// Should replace 0301 and 0331 by variables (date('mO1') and date('m31') for example), I let you handle this.
$prepared_query = $wpdb->prepare($query, array('0301', '0331'));

$result = $wpdb->get_results($prepared_query);

foreach($result as $r) {
  $cs_post = get_post($r->ID);

  echo '<p>';
  echo get_the_title($cs_post->ID) .'<br>';
  echo get_the_date('Y-m-d', $cs_post->ID) .'<br>';
  echo '</p>';

}
```

Not sure if it's the proper way but it works.